# AS3 Event Architecture Issue

Tags: actionscript-3, events

Before calling the function `addNodeFilled()` that uses an external bitmap file as a fill I must load the bitmap file in flash player using Loader class and wait for the loader to finish loading and fire `Event.COMPLETE` and execute the corresponding event handler `onComplete()`. To ensure this I have a while loop to wait for completion of loading in `addNodeFilled()`, but when running the program the program esp the loop goes on infinitely which means in flash the event handler is executed synchronously with the main sequence and can't execute until `addNodeFilled()` ends. Usually the code in `addNodeFilled()` is placed inside `onComplete` event handler but I am unable to do that and need to call `addNodeFilled()` whenever I wish but check for load completion, how can I do that?

```
var stitch:BitmapData = new BitmapData(16, 16);
var loaderStatus:String = "busy";           

var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
loader.load(new URLRequest("file:///E:/Projects/FlashDevelop/Terracotta/assets/Stripe.jpg"));

addNodeFilled(100, 100);



//function definitions===============================================


function onComplete(event:Event):void
{
  stitch = event.target.content.bitmapData;
  loaderStatus = "loaded";

} //onComplete

function addNodeFilled(posx:Number, posy:Number):void
{
  while(loaderStatus != "loaded")
  {
     trace("waiting for loader");
  }         

  var grid:Rectangle = new Rectangle(5, 5, 5, 5);
  var nodeDecal:Sprite = new Sprite();
  nodeDecal.graphics.beginBitmapFill(stitch, null, true, true);
  nodeDecal.graphics.drawRoundRectComplex(posx, posy, 80, 16, 0, 0, 4, 4);
  nodeDecal.scale9Grid = grid;
  addChild(nodeDecal);

} //addNodeFilled
```

Comment: Can't you move addNodeFilled() call to onComplete(event:Event)?

Comment: As I have already said that placing addNodeFilled() inside the event handler function is how its usually done but I can't because addNodeFilled() needs to be called again and again as and when new nodes are needed with different position parameters using the same user supplied bitmap image as fill. This situation of being forced to put the operative function call (here addNodeFilled) inside event handler function is limiting as it can be called just once with same parameters, usually the ensurance that something is done, that the operative function depends on, needs to be ensured once.

Answer (score 1):

AS3 executes on a single thread. You'll never receive any event notifications with that loop. I've mocked up a better pattern with the code below. You'll have to adapt it a bit to your needs. Notably, you'll have to move the drawing code out from `addNodeFilled()` and into its own method, that can be called from `addNodeFilled()` or from `onComplete()`, as necessary.

If there are multiple draw operations, you'll have to replace the drawPending variable with a queue, that gets executed after the asset is loaded. I've not mocked it here because it can increase the code complexity significantly.

```
var loader:Loader;
var loadPending:Boolean = false;
var isReady:Boolean = false;
var drawPending:Boolean = false;

function onComplete(event:Event):void
{
    if (drawPending)
    {
        // Perform drawing operating
    }
}

function triggerLoad():void
{
    loader = new Loader();
    loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    loader.load("http://example.com");

    loadPending = true;
}

function addNodeFilled(x:Number, y:Number):void
{
    if (!isReady)
    {
        triggerLoad();
        drawPending = true;

        return;
    }

    if (loadPending)
    {
        drawPending = true;

        return;
    }

    // Use asset as needed
}
```

Comment: +1 : simple and effective. In this case, the asset/drawing operation probably should be done in an additional method to be called at the end of addNodeFilled() or in onComplete().